# DotNetOpenId openIdRelyingParty Setup

Tags: c#, .net, installation, dotnetopenauth

I'm new to .Net and am trying to setup dotNetOpenID.  I'm simply trying to get the following line to build ok without getting any errors:

```
var openIdRelyingParty = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
```

Currently when I build, I get the following error:

> The type or namspace name'OpenIdrelyingParty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your project has a reference to DotNetOpenAuth.dll and add this line to the top of your code file:

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this package installed: https://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty/4.1.0.12182

And add this:`using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;`

[image]